# Is Sandbox solution deprecated from SharePoint online 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-online

Please help me out on this. I have tried a lot searching on this but didn't find anything. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Microsoft Wiki](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13373.sharepoint-2013-what-to-do-farm-solution-vs-sandbox-vs-app.aspx?tduid=%28d3491f4aa23639ea09d188095ee9e679%29%28256380%29%282459594%29%28TnL5HPStwNw-zzpEb8LgkgyQ6eXLHhH3VA%29%28%29):  **Deprecated**

[image: Overview from Microsoft Website]

Visit https://davidlozzi.com/2013/09/12/sharepoint-2013-sandbox-solutions-declarative-or-user-code-whats-dead-really/

Above link says: You can create sandbox solutions in SharePoint 2013, however they cannot contain server-side code; you can only create objects via declarative methods (XAML).

Comment: Nice ... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the activation of sandbox solutions in O65 has been disabled. Microsoft had publicly announced the same in different articles. In late July Microsoft started taking steps to complete the removal of code-based sandbox solutions as part of the phased approach announced in 2014 when they deprecated the feature.

http://dev.office.com/blogs/removing-code-based-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint-online

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdev/2014/01/14/deprecation-of-custom-code-in-sandboxed-solutions/

If you need to still use sandbox solutions in Sharepoint Online on a temporary basis, you will need to contact support with a valid reason. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that deactivation is only from Sandbox code-server:

https://dev.office.com/blogs/removing-code-based-sandbox-solutions-in-sharepoint-online

Note that currently, we do not plan to deprecate or remove support for declarative (no-code) sandboxed solutions.